# python argument and position on how to pass file

Tags: python, file, tkinter, arguments

i need to pass the filename on a opencv img read how can i do that

```
class show_image:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = window
        frame = Frame(window)
        frame.pack(side=BOTTOM, padx=15, pady=15)

    def showimage(self):

        self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd(), title="Select Image File", filetypes=(
            ("JPG File", "*.jpg"), ("PNG File", "*.png"), ("All file", "how are you .txt")))
        self.img = Image.open(self.filename)
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
        self.lbl.configure(image=self.img)
        self.lbl.image = self.img


    def backtovehiclecount(self):
        win = Toplevel()
        Thesis.VehicleCounting.Vehicle_Counting(win, self.filename)
        self.window.withdraw()


def page():
    window = Tk()
    show_image(window)
    window.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    page()
```

how can i pass the file name on img=cv2.imread()self.filename but theres a Thesis.VehicleCounting.Vehicle_Counting(win, self.filename)
"TypeError: Vehicle_Counting.**init**() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given" error

```
class Vehicle_Counting:

    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = window
     
    def Counter(self,filename):
        self.filename = filename
        vd = VehicleDetector()
        img = cv2.imread(self.filename)
        vehicle_boxes = vd.detect_vehicles(img)
        self.vehicle_count = len(vehicle_boxes)
        for box in vehicle_boxes:
            x, y, w, h = box
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (25, 0, 180), 3)
            cv2.putText(img, "Vehicles:" + str(self.vehicle_count), (20, 50), 0, 2, (100, 200, 0), 

        cv2.imshow("Cars", img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the actual error.

Comment: .VehicleCounting.Vehicle_Counting(win, self.filename)
TypeError: Vehicle_Counting.__init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: Please add that to the question.

Comment: alright done sir

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre]. debug your code (learn how to debug). this is expected on this site. see: [help/on-topic]. please **do not** tag OpenCV when your question isn't about opencv but merely about file paths.

Answer (score -1):

Your `Vehicle_Counting.__init__()` only takes 2 parameters: the implicit `self`, and `window`.

In this line

```py
Thesis.VehicleCounting.Vehicle_Counting(win, self.filename)
```

You're providing it with three parameters: the implicit `self`, `win`, and `self.filename`. Either add `filename` to the list of `__init__` arguments, or don't pass it to the initialization.

Comment: how will i pass the filename on the opencv without adding filename?

Comment: when i add file name on __init__ this happens TypeError: show_image.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filename'